# Core data error: Unsupported expression type (11, SIZE)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

The error happens when I try to create following `NSPredicate`:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "size = nil")
```

The error is as follows:

> Unsupported expression type (11, SIZE)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `size` is reserved word in Core Data. This can be fixed like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "#size = nil")
```